# How do you setup relationships with many foreign keys from the same table in PHP ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm

I am building a real estate related website that real estate agents and investors can use to track properties submitted in the system and keep track of who is owed what profits. I have the following tables that I am having trouble figuring out how to setup the relationships for in my models using [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/):

**properties**

- id
- primary_profit_sharing
- secondary_profit_sharing
- commission
- referral_payment

**users**

- id
- name
- email

**payments**

- id
- type (commission, referral_payment, etc.)
- property_id
- user_id

What is the proper way to setup these relationships using PHP ActiveRecord? I would like to be able to access the user information for each payment by something like `$property->commission` and `$property->referral_payment` but I can't figure out how to setup the relationships in the models to allow that.

I currently have payments belonging to users and properties, and users/payments have many payments. All the information I was is returned in the query, but not in an accessible ways. I have `$property->users` but no way of getting the user information for a particular payment type.

The only way I can think of to accomplish what I'm looking for is to setup a table for each payment type, but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `payments` table, instead of using `property_id` and `user_id`, maybe you should use `fk_object` as the foreign key and do your joins using that field. `fk_object` represents the id of the user or the id of the property.